# MPL: How to explain that your countermodel interpretation "works"?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Say, for example, I have this tableau:

[image: ◻(p∨q)⊃(◻p∨◻q)]

How would one go about explaining how the countermodel,

[image: countermodel]

actually works? In other words, how when looking through the tableau should you apply the truth values in order to prove your counter-interpretation?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I suppose, I'm confused about how to deal with the modal ◻ and ◇ operators in the RAA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four truh-conditions of the counter-model mean :

> $w_1 \nvDash p, w_1 \vDash q, w_2 \vDash p, w_w \nvDash q$.

This implies : $w_1 \vDash p \lor q$ and $w_2 \vDash p \lor q$.

I.e. $p \lor q$ is true in every world, i.e. it is *necessarily* true : $w_1,w_2 \vDash \square (p \lor q)$.

But at the same time they imply : $w_1, w_2 \nvDash \square p$, because $p$ is not true in every world, and also $w_1, w_2\nvDash \square q$.

Thus, $w_1,w_2 \nvDash \square p \lor \square q$.

> Conclusion : the *antecedent* of the formula is true, while the *consequent* is false, i.e. the formula is false.